# Why does immutable.ParMap.mapValues return ParMap instead of immutable.ParMap?

Tags: scala

In my Scala 2.11.6 application I have defined an `immutable.ParMap` like so:

```
  object Foos {
    val foos: immutable.ParMap[String, Foo] = immutable.ParMap(
     ...
    )
  }
```

Later on, I'd like to create a new `immutable.ParMap` using the same keys, so I use `mapValues`:

```
 val fooServices: immutable.ParMap[String, FooService] = Exchanges.exchanges mapValues (_.fooService)
```

Scala complains

> Expression of type ParMap[String, FooService] does not conform to
>   expected type ParMap[String, FooService].

As a workaround I can use a for comprehension, which the compiler permits:

```
val fooServices: immutable.ParMap[String, FooService] =
    for ((name, ex) <- Foos.foos) yield name -> foo.fooService
```

But it would nice to be able to use the library functions that are designed for this exact task. Why can't `mapValues` infer the most specific type here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of inferring the most specific type.  It's actually an instance of `scala.collection.parallel.ParMapLike$$anon$2`, which is a view of the underlying map (the created map forwards all operations to the original).

It could have been created separately for the immutable and mutable branches, but to have better code-sharing in the library, it was just created once, in `ParMapLike`.  So the return type is correct in that the type of immutable `.mapValues` is the same as that of mutable `.mapValues`.

If you don't want a view (implemented as a proxy) but to actually regenerate the collection, use `map` instead.  I.e. `xs.mapValues(v => f(v))` becomes `xs.map{ case (k,v) => (k, f(v)) }` and then a new immutable `ParMap` will be generated and typed as such.

Comment: Ahh, this makes perfect sense now. I didn't realize `mapValues` was actually returning a view. It's a bit confusing, because with other collections (e.g. `Seq`) you need to call `.view` explicitly.

Comment: @user1885198 - `mapValues` _always_ returns a view, parallel or not.  That it does so is kind of surprising, but it is consistent.  Maybe it should be called `valueView`.  There is no "map part of every entry" method in `Seq` so it's not really comparable.